# Query execution showing error as login failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to retrive the table values from other server

Query

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'OPSERVER', @srvproduct = 'SQL Server'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', @rmtuser = 'SA', @rmtpassword = 'SA'

SELECT * FROM OPSERVER.VENUS.dbo.TABL1
```

The above query is showing error as login failed for user 'SA'

Treid Query

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'OPSERVER', @srvproduct = 'SQL Server'

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', 
  @locallogin = 'sa', 
  @rmtuser = 'sa', 
  @rmtpassword = 'sa'

SELECT * FROM OPSERVER.VENUS.dbo.TABLE1



Showing error as "Login failed for user 'sa'"
```

What wrong in my query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide password for remote sa account, like this:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', @rmtuser = 'SA', @rmtpassword = 'RemoteSaPassword'
```

Or if you run under local sa account

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', 
  @locallogin = 'sa', 
  @rmtuser = 'sa', 
  @rmtpassword = 'RemoteSaPassword'
```

FOr windows auth:

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', 
  @locallogin = 'domain\username', 
  @rmtuser = 'sa', 
  @rmtpassword = 'RemoteSaPassword'
```

Or

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', 
  @useself = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: I felt very bad myself, again it is showing error as Login FAILED FOR user sa'

Comment: You replaced the string **RemoteSaPassword** with a proper sa password on server OPSERVER?

Comment: Password is SA ONLY, BUT IT IS SHOWING ERROR AGAIN....

Comment: If it is windows authentication means, what i have to give...?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: What do you mean by @rmtpassword, is a system password...? or what..?

Comment: @rmtpassword - the password of user sa on server OPSERVER

Comment: Still i am not getting, can you check my question plz... i did anything wrong...?

Comment: Or remote login sa has other password, or remote server does not accept Sql Server authentication. Try to connect to remote server with sa/sa from Management Studio

Comment: same user name and password, In select query we can pass user name and password...?

Comment: In select - no. You tried to connect from ssms? Check also - may be you have any other logins mapped to this linked server?

Comment: i am new to linked server, what is ssms..?

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` has the parameter `@useself`. BOL says about it (marked by me):

> [ @useself = ] 'TRUE' | 'FALSE' | 'NULL'
>
> Determines whether to connect to rmtsrvname by impersonating local logins or explicitly submitting a login and password. The data type is varchar(8), **with a default of TRUE**.
>
> A value of **TRUE specifies that logins use their own credentials to connect to rmtsrvname, with the rmtuser and rmtpassword arguments being ignored**. FALSE specifies that the rmtuser and rmtpassword arguments are used to connect to rmtsrvname for the specified locallogin. If rmtuser and rmtpassword are also set to NULL, no login or password is used to connect to the linked server.

I think you need to try to add the login with @useself='false':

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname = 'OPSERVER', 
  @useself='false',
  @locallogin = 'sa', 
  @rmtuser = 'sa', 
  @rmtpassword = 'RemoteSaPassword'
```